# Group-wise total in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a pandas table like below with `groupby` applied to get Groups 0, 1 and 2 as follows:

| Group 0 | Group 1 | Group 2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X1 | 577.5000 | 6 |
|  |  | 894.8700 | 2 |
|  | X2 | 2697.3100 | 48 |
|  |  | 2697.3100 | 1 |
|  | B3 | 2697.3100 | 30 |
| B | C12 | 34.2700 | 9 |
|  |  | 39.2700 | 3 |

I would like to get group wise total in pandas like below:

| Group 0 | Group 1 | Group 2 | Count | Group 1 Total by Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X1 | 577.5000 | 6 | 8 |
|  |  | 894.8700 | 2 | 8 |
|  | X2 | 2697.3100 | 48 | 49 |
|  |  | 2697.3100 | 1 | 49 |
|  | B3 | 2697.3100 | 30 | 30 |
| B | C12 | 34.2700 | 9 | 12 |
|  |  | 39.2700 | 3 | 12 |

I am able to calculate cumulative sum using `df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumsum()` but now sure if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` to transform a `sum` call over the groups.

```py
df['Group 1 Total by Count'] = df.groupby(['Group 0', 'Group 1'])['Count'].transform('sum')
```

[image: res]